# How to check if 2 list or 2 maps are equals exactly to each others in length and content

Tags: dart

I have 2 dynamic lists & 2 maps

**2 List**

```
 List<dynamic> superDeepList1 = [
      [
        {
          'name': 'Alice',
          'age': 30,
          'height': 5.8,
          'isStudent': false,
          'friends': ['Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
          'address': {
            'street': '123 Main St',
            'city': 'Wonderland',
            'zipcode': '12345'
          }
        },
        {
          'name': 'Bob',
          'age': 25,
          'height': 6.1,
          'isStudent': true,
          'friends': ['Alice', 'Carol'],
          'address': {
            'street': '456 Elm St',
            'city': 'Dreamville',
            'zipcode': '54321'
          }
        },
        'This is a string item'
      ],
      [
        {
          'name': 'Carol',
          'age': 28,
          'height': 5.5,
          'isStudent': true,
          'friends': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'David'],
          'address': {
            'street': '789 Oak St',
            'city': 'Fantasia',
            'zipcode': '67890'
          }
        },
        {
          'name': 'David',
          'age': 32,
          'height': 5.9,
          'isStudent': false,
          'friends': ['Alice', 'Carol'],
          'address': {
            'street': '321 Pine St',
            'city': 'Neverland',
            'zipcode': '09876'
          }
        },
        'Another string item'
      ]
    ];



List<dynamic> superDeepList2 = [
  [
    {
      'name': 'Alfdsfe',
      'age': 36,
      'height': 5.8,
      'isStudent': false,
      'friends': ['Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
      'address': {
        'street': '123 Main St',
        'city': 'Wonderland',
        'zipcode': '12345'
      }
    },
    {
      'name': 'Bob',
      'age': 25,
      'height': 6.1,
      'isStudent': true,
      'friends': ['Alice', 'Carol'],
      'address': {
        'street': '456 Elm St',
        'city': 'Dreamville',
        'zipcode': '54321'
      }
    },
    'This is a string item'
  ],
  [
    {
      'name': 'Carol',
      'age': 28,
      'height': 5.5,
      'isStudent': true,
      'friends': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'David'],
      'address': {
        'street': '789 Oak St',
        'city': 'Fantasia',
        'zipcode': '67890'
      }
    },
    {
      'name': 'David',
      'age': 32,
      'height': 5.9,
      'isStudent': false,
      'friends': ['Alice', 'Carol'],
      'address': {
        'street': '321 Pine St',
        'city': 'Neverland',
        'zipcode': '09876'
      }
    },
    'Another string item'
  ]
];
```

**2 Map**

```
Map<String, dynamic> superDeepMap1 = {
  'outerKey1': {
    'innerKey1': {
      'nestedKey1': 'value1',
      'nestedKey2': 'value2',
      'nestedKey3': {
        'deepNestedKey1': 'deepValue1',
        'deepNestedKey2': 'deepValue2'
      }
    },
    'innerKey2': {
      'nestedKey4': 'value4',
      'nestedKey5': 'value5'
    }
  },
  'outerKey2': {
    'innerKey3': {
      'nestedKey6': 'value6',
      'nestedKey7': 'value7'
    },
    'innerKey4': {
      'nestedKey8': 'value8',
      'nestedKey9': 'value9'
    }
  }
};


Map<String, dynamic> superDeepMap2 = {
  'outerKey1': {
    'innerKey1': {
      'nestedKey1': 'value1',
      'nestedKey2': 'value2',
      'nestedKey3': {
        'deepNestedKey1': 'deepValue1',
        'deepNestedKey2': 'deepValue2'
      }
    },
    'innerKey2': {
      'nestedKey4': 'value4',
      'nestedKey5': 'value5'
    }
  },
  'outerKey2': {
    'innerKey3': {
      'nestedKey6': 'value6',
      'nestedKey7': 'value7'
    },
    'innerKey4': {
      'nestedKey8': 'value8',
      'nestedKey9': 'value9'
    }
  }
};
```

How to check if `superDeepList1` == `superDeepList2` in length and content exactly. And the same question with Maps.

Best way i find so far is following

https://pub.dev/packages/collection

```
bool listsEqual = const DeepCollectionEquality().equals(superDeepList1,superDeepList2);
```

But is there short code without using external package  ?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far that didn't work.

Comment: ListEquality().equals(superDeepList1 , superDeepList2 ); does not print expected result

Comment: What does it print ? You can add those information to your question using the "Edit" function.

Comment: "but is there short code without using external package ?" No, there is no built-in way.  If you cannot use external packages, then you will need to compare elements manually.  Note that `package:collection` is from the Dart team at Google, so any concerns about using third-party code aren't really warranted.

Comment: @jamesdlin Do you think this plugin is big in size?

Comment: I would expect tree-shaking to remove unused code, but really you should try it and do your own analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is nothing similar to `DeepCollectionEquality` in the platform libraries.
That's why it's in `package:collection`, which is intended to have functionality that is not in `dart:collection`, and which doesn't *need* to be in the platform libraries.

You can write your own code. It's easiest if you assume that all the maps are standard equality-based hash maps. If the maps use different notions of equality, comparing them is ... tricky. So don't do that.

It's simple code then:

```dart
bool equals(Object? v1, Object? v2) {
  if (identical(v1, v2) || v1 == v2) return true;
  if (v1 is Map) return v2 is Map && mapsEqual(v1, v2);
  if (v1 is List) return v2 is List && listsEqual(v1, v2);
  if (v1 is Set) return v2 is Set && setsEqual(v1, v2);
  if (v1 is double) {
    return v1.isNaN && v2 is double && v2.isNaN;
  }
  return false;
}

bool mapsEqual(Map map1, Map map2) {
  if (map1.length != map2.length) return false;
  for (var key in map1.keys) {
    var value1 = map1[key];
    var value2 = map2[key];
    if (value1 == null && (value2 != null || !map2.containsKey(key))) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!equals(value1, value2)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

bool setsEqual(Set v1, Set v2) {
  if (v1.length != v2.length) return false;
  for (var v in v1) {
    if (!v2.contains(v)) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

bool listsEqual(List v1, List v2) {
  if (v1.length != v2.length) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < v1.length; i++) {
    if (!equals(v1[i], v2[i])) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```